# LibGDX + Eclipse | Can't load in .tmx () file

Tags: java, eclipse, file, libgdx, tmx

I started about a week ago with libGDX and I have a problem loading in a tmx. Tiled Map. 
As far as I see the game doesn't find the "test.tmx", but I don't know why! The path is correct as far as I can see.

I use "Tiled" as the Map Editor. The Layer Format is Base64.

This Screenshot showing the Code I use to load in the tmx. file and the Project Structure:
http://abload.de/img/tmxgpptc.png

I get the following error Message:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: res/map/test.tmx
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:83)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:113)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:101)
at de.knightsquest.states.Play.<init>(Play.java:59)
at de.knightsquest.handler.GameStateManager.getState(GameStateManager.java:35)
at de.knightsquest.handler.GameStateManager.pushState(GameStateManager.java:46)
at de.knightsquest.handler.GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:20)
at de.knightsquest.game.Game.create(Game.java:38)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: res\map\test.tmx (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:164)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:81)
... 9 more
```

Comment: Is the file correctly formatted?
How do you run your project - do you export your resources to buildpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [this wiki article about file handling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling).

You have to place the `res\map\test.tmx` inside your android project in the `assets` folder. The way you load the map assumes an internal (android/assets) file path.

Furthermore I'd advise you to load the `TiledMap` via an `AssetManager`.

Comment: Thx! Yeah that was the problem. I will read the wiki article. :)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you followed the tutorial of ForeignGuyMike, you will have one project, but in general you auto-generate your projects with the LibGDX-Tool. When loading ressources LibGDX looks up in the assets folder of the android project. Instead of using the res-folder from before, use the assets-folder.
If you auto-generated the project the dependencies are all correctly established and by calling the load method, libgdx looks up the file in the **assets-folder** in your **android project**.
Thing is your filepath should now only be **"maps/test.tmx"** since it's already looking in the assets folder.

In general it's the same idea as the answer above I guess...
I just disliked the idea of moving the whole folder structure, because assets are our ressources...

Comment: Superb! Thanks a lot!